# gdb: No symbol "_v8_internal_Print_Object" in current context

Tags: node.js, gdb, v8

I want to compile v8 engine on my mac(10.14.6 mojave) and use gdb for debugging. So I do the step below.

```
tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.debug
ninja -C out.gn/x64.debug d8
```

And I import the script(/path/to/v8/tools/gdbinit) to use 'job' command.

**~/.gdbinit**:

```
set startup-with-shell off
source /Users/xxxx/pwndbg/gdbinit.py
source ~/.gdbinit_v8
source /Users/xxxx/v8/v8/tools/gdb-v8-support.py
```

And then I use

```
sudo gdb ./d8
```

When I input `job 0x284a9de0e361`
It returns `No symbol "_v8_internal_Print_Object" in current context.`It seems that this function should be declared by v8, but I can’t use it. Did I miss what configuration caused this interface not to be exposed? Please help me if anyone know what happens. Thanks a lot！

Comment: Did you start the program? What's the output of GDB's `backtrace` command? (Also, why `sudo`?)

Comment: I confirm that I started the program. I do the same install steps on my ubuntu 16.04, all the commands I mentioned in the problem works. I didn't sign my gdb 8.0.1 with a system certificate so I use sudo.